Flutter - Needs to overlap the card and should be expand
Here am trying to archive the design as like sequence generating the cards and should top overlapping each card

Selected card should be expanded &  remaining cards should go down

I tried below the code to overlap the card one by one
class MerchantCards extends StatefulWidget {
  const MerchantCards({super.key});

  @override
  State<MerchantCards> createState() => _MerchantCardsState();
}

class _MerchantCardsState extends State<MerchantCards> {
  int? _selectedCardIndex;

  void _onCardTap(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedCardIndex = index; // Toggle selection
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Overlapping Animated Cards'),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: 3, // Number of cards
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Align(
              heightFactor: _selectedCardIndex == index ? 2 : 0.3,
              child: GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () => _onCardTap(index),
                  child: SizedBox(
                    height: 200,
                    width: 300,
                    child: Card(
                      color: Color((math.Random().nextDouble() * 0xFFFFFF).toInt())
                              .withOpacity(1.0),
                      child: Center(
                        child: Text("Card ${index + 1}"),
                      ),
                    ),
                  )));
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}


I had like to expect the card should be expand with animation, i have attached the refrense
Card overlapped image
Overlaped mode
Card expanded image
Expanded mode
Here is the functionality for like animation to expand
Expected functionality

something like this: https://gist.github.com/pskink/81aa39d1eefd58d72fb8b945499487ec?

Hello @pskink, thanks for the update, I have seen the code, and it looks like the accordion item builder returns the header and body, but I am looking for only one card, if we select the card, the next card I mean the remaining card should be going down, here the image selected image has shown as highlighted and remainings are down (https://i.sstatic.net/O9yCqIr1.png)

I would give this package a try card_swiper
